# How can I batch merge multiple HDR sets of bracketed photos together in Darktable?

Tags: hdr, darktable

How can I batch merge multiple HDR sets of bracketed photos together in Darktable?

I have 1,600 photos in a folder. They are all bracketed sets to create HDRs with. They are all in order, and there are five brackets for each set. There should be 320 HDR merges created from these 1600 files, with 5 photos used for each HDR set.

I want to select all 1600 photos, choose "convert to HDR in sets of 5", and have Darktable automatically create the 320 HDR merge images for me.

Can I do that automatically? I really don't want to manually select five photos at a time and click the HDR button, over and over again, 320 times.

Comment: Maybe Hudin will be more appropriate in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure how valid this is, but from [this](https://discuss.pixls.us/t/command-line-way-to-make-export-hdr-from-raw-file/18952) forum, there is a comment that says "Darktable’s build in HDR doesn’t do auto alignment of images, which is a short coming for many images.".  I'd make an answer, but I only know what I just googled.  So take it with a large suitcase of salt.